# Adding business methods to auto-generated hibernate entities

Tags: java, hibernate

We're working on a new system that uses hibernate for persistence. As the schema changes we're using NetBeans to regenerate the entity classes.

As the system is evolving we are finding a lot of functionality that is crying out to be added as business methods in the entities, but because we are regenerating these classes from time-to-time we are reluctant to do so.

Is there an elegant way of being able to regenerate entity classes and still add business logic, such as in a subclass that Hibernate would use?

Many thanks,

Ian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. However, I have a solution for you.

The business logic code has to go somewhere - the question is, where to put it. You *could* put it on the `@Entity`, marking business getters with `@Transient`, but good design says to use a separate class [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) class.

Separating business from persistence code follows the ["high cohesion"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29#High_cohesion) design principle, giving you:

- Your entity class remains clean - ie it has code *solely* related to persistence. Furthermore, because you haven't added anything to it, it can safely be regenerated at any time.
- Your "business logic" class (often named the same as the entity class, but with `"Dao"` added to the name, eg `CustomerDao`) has methods to deal with (usually course-grained) behaviour. Also, unit testing is usually easier, because you *don't* want to test the entity methods (you can assume they work - it ain't your code) and can more easily design your code to allow easy mocking of an entity (that isn't a *real* entity)

You may be able to leverage some reuse by creating a typed abstract DAO class for behaviour common to entities (where/if it makes sense).

Comment: +1
If you go this route of using DAOs, then take a look at https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects.

Comment: Thanks for those replies. I was hoping that someone would suggest something a bit more OO, but I guess no one is using hibernate in that way. We have got DAOs for each of our entities so that is a possible home for this functionality.

Comment: It turns out I'm not the only person who's unhappy with dumb entity objects: The Anemic Domain Model anti-pattern http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: So say I have a `Fee` entity.  This fee has an `amountTotal` and an `amountPaid` field that is persisted.  I want to be able to test in my view if the fee is completely paid off.  I was thinking that I could make a `@Transient` getter that compares `amountTotal` to `amountPaid` and returns a boolean.  This transient getter could be called from the view.  You mention, though, that this is not good design.  Why is that?

Comment: @mattblang if there's just one such field in your entire system, I would just add a transient getter, but if there's more than one, even in another entity, I would use the DAO pattern, because you don't want a mixture of both. You want a design where everyone knows where code is, so things should be consistent. Also, it's worth noting that if you have one now, you'll likely have another soon.

Comment: If you put business logic into DAOs, there are not DAOs anymore. It's more like a mixture of DAO and Service Objects.

Comment: @jimmyt actually, far from being "good" design, having *no* business logic in your DAO is actually an *anti-pattern* - read Martin Fowler's short but highly informative article on the [Anemic Domain Model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)

Comment: @Bohemian The logic should be in the entity classes itself not the DAO. Martin Fowler's article is supporting this not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between business model and business logic. 
The logic acts over the model to provide a service.
Usually the entities should reflect the model, while DAOs and Services should reflect the business logic. For me it is strange to have business logic inside the entities.